# How does Linux timer works in kernel

Tags: timer, linux-kernel

I'm reading the Linux timer code and found that the each cpu will initialize it's own timer list.

If user space calls add_timer, the timer will add to the kernel.

My question:
Is this timer will be added for each cpu's timer list? Or it will only adds to current cpu A, and only CPU A can process this timer in the future.

Comment: User mode can't call `add_timer`.

Comment: Why would a process running on CPU A add a timer on CPU B?